# In NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification what is the difference between NSUpdatedObjectsKey and NSRefreshedObjectsKey

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsnotifications

The documentation says;

`NSUpdatedObjectsKey`
Key for the set of objects that were updated.

`NSRefreshedObjectsKey`
Key for the set of objects that were refreshed but were not dirtied in the scope of this context.

What does this actually mean. I just want to know what has changed, so do I need to watch both these keys?

Comment: See [Purpose of NSRefreshedObjectsKey](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12744328/4244136).

Answer (score 5):

`NSUpdatedObjectsKey` means that a property of the object has changed.  However if you set an property to the same values that was already there then it will also appear as `NSUpdatedObjectsKey` even if nothing really changed. (ie `issue.issueId = issue.issueId` will cause the object to be "changed").

`NSRefreshedObjectsKey` means that the object was refetched from the store.  If you are using more than one context at the same time then the object may have changed when you weren't looking. So calling `refreshObject:mergeChanges:` on the context for those objects will cause them to be refetched from the store.  This does not mean that they have change - but they may have.

In regards to using them, I am not sure why you would need either.  Since `NSPersistentContainer`, I haven't had any reason to use `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` at all, as `NSPersistentContainer` manages all of the context merging and updates for me.  When I did manage my own core data stack I mostly just passed along the entire notification to `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:`.   I never called `refreshObject:mergeChanges:` as I had other ways of making sure that the contexts remained in sync, so I never had any RefreshedObjects.

I'm not sure if answered your question, I hope that helps.

Comment: NSPersistentContainer is iOS10+ so if you need to support iOS9 like me then you can't use it.

Comment: Yes, that is true.  If you need a good pre-NSPersistentContainer core data stack I highly recommend looking at https://vimeo.com/89370886.  The setup described in the video is very similar in many ways to NSPersistentContainer.  In that setup as well there is no need to ever refresh objects, but you would have to make sure that the objects in `NSUpdatedObjectsKey` and `NSDeletedObjectsKey` are faulted in the context before merging if you want to ensure that fetchedResultsController are updated.

Comment: Ok i will try to be more elaborate... I have two contexts one main, and one private. When i save private context, i merge its changes to main context. I also register obesrver to changes to main context. So scenario goes like this -> change property on entity in private context, save, then i get in notification in main context that entity has been refreshed. I never myself call the refreshObject:mergeChanges: